# Problems with complex query

Tags: sql, ms-access

There are two tables.

In the first I have columns:

- `id` - a person
- `time` - the time of receiving the bonus (timestamp)
- `money` - size of bonus

And the second:

- `id`
- `time` - time of getting a rank (timestamp)
- `range` - military rank (int)

The task is to withdraw the amount and number of bonuses received by people in the rank of captain (`range = 7`) with aggregation by day.

I have no ideas how to do a table with this data. I can summarize data by all days such as

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW Payment.user_id AS user_id, Sum(IIf(IsNull(Payment.money),0,Payment.money)) AS [Sum - money], Count(Payment.money) AS [Count - Payment], Format(Payment.time, "Short Date") as day
FROM Payment
GROUP BY Payment.user_id, Format (Payment.time, "Short Date")
Having ((Count(Payment.money) > 0));
```

Can you help me with second part and summarize them? thanks

For example: first table (Payment):

```
user_id time    money
a   01.01.10 00:00:00   15,00 
a   01.01.10 10:00:00   2,00 
a   03.01.10 00:00:00   3,00 
c   04.01.10 00:00:00   4,00 
c   04.01.10 00:05:00   5,00 
d   06.01.10 00:00:00   6,00 
e   07.01.10 00:00:00   7,00 
e   08.01.10 00:00:00   8,00
```

The second one:

```
user_id time    range
a   01.01.10 00:00:00   6
a   01.01.10 09:00:00   7
a   04.01.10 00:00:00   8
b   04.01.10 00:00:00   4
c   04.01.10 00:05:00   7
d   06.01.10 00:00:00   5
e   07.01.10 00:00:00   6
f   08.01.10 00:00:00   6
g   08.01.10 00:00:00   7
```

I expected:

```
user_id time sum
a  01.01.10  2
a  03.01.10  3
c  04.01.10  5
```

Comment: MySQL <> MS Access. Please don't spam tag various RDBMS

Comment: Edit question to show sample data and desired result. What problems - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? Build aggregate query then join to second table and apply filter criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible method using joins:

```sql
select t1.user_id, datevalue(p.time) as [time], sum(p.money) as [sum]
from
    (
        (select t.user_id, t.time from rank t where t.range = 7) t1
        inner join payment p on t1.user_id = p.user_id
    ) 
    left join
    (select t.user_id, t.time from rank t where t.range > 7) t2 on p.user_id = t2.user_id
where
    p.time >= t1.time and (t2.user_id is null or p.time < t2.time)
group by
    t1.user_id, datevalue(p.time)
```

I have assumed that your second table is called `rank` (this was not stated in your question).

Here, the subquery `t1` obtains the set of users with `range = 7` (captain), and the subquery `t2` obtains the set of users with `range > 7`. I then select all records with a payment date greater than or equal to the date of promotion to captain, but less than any subsequent promotion (if it exists).

This yields the following result:

```
+---------+------------+------+
| user_id |    time    | sum  |
+---------+------------+------+
| a       | 01/01/2010 | 2.00 |
| a       | 03/01/2010 | 3.00 |
| c       | 04/01/2010 | 5.00 |
+---------+------------+------+
```

---

Unless I have misunderstood, I would argue that your expected result is incorrect as the payment below occurs **before** `user_id = c` achieved the rank of captain:

```
c   04.01.10 00:00:00   4,00
```

```
c   04.01.10 00:05:00   7
```

Comment: Thanks, but in situation when bonus is received after getting a rank 8, this bonus will be showed in that solution, but i need only bonuses on 7 rank. How I can set upper bound by time? (For getting rank 8)

Comment: @mitrik_bnr You make a good point - I have rewritten my answer above.

Comment: Perfect! Ideal work at my example. Thank you very much